# Multiple forms on 1 html

Tags: html, forms

I am trying to do the following. Have 6 different forms on an html file which are all post forms. I want to have the buttons at the top of the page and each of the corrispond to a specific form.

What is the best way to achieve this?

I can't seem to get the post methods working in the destination files.

Comment: Use Javascript to submit the forms on click of the buttons.

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: @zedfoxus Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this below. We create two buttons on top of the page. They both call `submitform` JavaScript function but with different parameters. The parameter is the name of the form. The function just takes the name of the form and submits it.

```
form.php
--------

<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($_POST);
    echo '</pre>';
}
?>

<button id="button1" name="b1" onclick="submitform('form1');">Submit Form1</button>
<button id="button2" name="b2" onclick="submitform('form2');">Submit Form2</button>

<form id="form1" action="form.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" id="i1" name="i1">
<input type="hidden" id="h1" name="i1" value="form1">
</form>

<form id="form2" action="form.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" id="i2" name="i2">
<input type="hidden" id="h2" name="i2" value="form2">
</form>

<script>
function submitform(formname) {
    document.forms[formname].submit();
}
</script>
```

Result:

```
When you press Submit Form1:
Array
(
    [i1] => form1
)

When you press Submit Form2:
Array
(
    [i1] => form2
)
```